# Setting flags before and after doing work

Tags: if-statement, refactoring

Sometimes I find myself doing the following:

```
if (some_condition)
    set_flag(true)

do_some_work();
// more work ...

if (some_condition)
    set_flag(false)
```

It often feels hacked together. Is there a way I can refactor this so it is cleaner?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are `some_condition` conditions the same?

Comment: Where is the get_flag?  Maybe you could post more detailed psuedo code?

Comment: @zanegray get_flag would be called through a method call. e.g. inside the body of do_some_work()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opion, I think that the suggested psuedo code is fine for several reasons: 
  **1.** Checking a flag rather than checking the condition over again should be more efficient
  **2.** Additional abstraction / refactoring may only cause more of a headache down the road and seems to be **non-value-added** work that could better be used somewhere else
  **3.** Using flags is usually readable **if** they have meaningful names (or method names in this case)